# FileVault unlock startup screen

Tags: startup, login, filevault

I don't want anybody turning on my Mac seeing my name and user account picture (all user account configured on the computer, actually!) just because it defaults to choosing a user to unlock the drive.

- How can I get two simple username/password text fields instead of the "personal" login screen? This is possible for a "normal" login screen...

Answer (score 3):

There is no way currently to get login / password blanks at the FileVault 2 preboot login screen.

Comment: If anyone on the planet knew a workaround for this, my money would be on [Rich Trouton](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/fdesetup-authrestart-filevault-2s-one-time-encryption-bypass-feature/). I'm looking forward to hearing you speak in Minneapolis at the [JAMF conference](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/events/user-conferences/jamf-nation-user-conference-2012) :-)

Answer (score -3):

This is easy to do.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click on "Users & Groups"
3. At the bottom of the left window pane click on "Login Options"
4. Change the value of "Display login window as" from "List of users" to "Name and
   password"

Now the login screen will show two simple username/password text fields.

Comment: Nope... not with FileVault... have you tested this?

Comment: @Hair of the Dog: The login screen is NOT the Filevault unlock screen.